# 'Else' must be preceded by a matching 'If' or 'ElseIf'

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

**I cant run my program due to this error. Can somebody help me? Thanks.**

Public Class Login

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    If tbx_username.Text <> "" And tbx_pass.Text <> "" Then
        Dim SM As New SubjectMaintenance
        Dim dr = SM.openSel(SqlString.getSQLSelect(Account.tablename, Account.si_data_username & "='" & tbx_username.Text & "' and " & Account.si_data_pwd & "='" & tbx_pass.Text & "'"), CommandType.Text)

        While dr.Read
            GUI.accnt.pData_id = dr(Account.si_data_id)
            Me.Hide()
            GUI.Show()
    **Else**

            GUI.accnt.pData_pwd = dr(Account.si_data_pwd)
            GUI.accnt.pData_username = dr(Account.si_data_username)
            GUI.accnt.pData_lname = dr(Account.si_data_lname)
            GUI.accnt.pData_fname = dr(Account.si_data_fname)
            GUI.accnt.pData_mname = dr(Account.si_data_mname)
        End While
        SM.closeConDr()
        If GUI.accnt.pData_id > 0 Then
            MessageBox.Show("Login Failed!")
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

End Class

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot put an `else` inside `while end-while`, the `if-else-end if` and `while-end while` are standalone statements, so you can mix them as follows:

```
while
 if
 else
 end if
end while
```

or

```
if
 while
 end while
else
 while
 end while
end if
```

The only way to break into a nested statement is the `GoTo` statement, it moves the instruction pointer unconditionally to the specified label.

Answer (score 0):

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
If tbx_username.Text <> "" And tbx_pass.Text <> "" Then
    Dim SM As New SubjectMaintenance
    Dim dr = SM.openSel(SqlString.getSQLSelect(Account.tablename, Account.si_data_username & "='" & tbx_username.Text & "' and " & Account.si_data_pwd & "='" & tbx_pass.Text & "'"), CommandType.Text)

    While dr.Read
        GUI.accnt.pData_id = dr(Account.si_data_id)
        Me.Hide()
        GUI.Show()

    End While
**Else**  'Try moving the else below the end while or above the while

        GUI.accnt.pData_pwd = dr(Account.si_data_pwd)
        GUI.accnt.pData_username = dr(Account.si_data_username)
        GUI.accnt.pData_lname = dr(Account.si_data_lname)
        GUI.accnt.pData_fname = dr(Account.si_data_fname)
        GUI.accnt.pData_mname = dr(Account.si_data_mname)
    SM.closeConDr()
    If GUI.accnt.pData_id > 0 Then
        MessageBox.Show("Login Failed!")
    End If
  End If
End Sub
```

'Try moving the else below the end while or above the while